# Where is here or what is here?

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if I could say 'Where is here' when I show students a flash card of a 'supermarket'!
Can i ask them "Where is here" or I should say "What is here"?
Eg: (showing a flash card to the students)
- Where is here?
+ Here's/It's a supermarket.

Answer (score 4):

Neither "Where is here?" nor "What is here?" are natural questions for the response you want.

It is more natural to ask **"What is this?"**

The full question is implied:

> What is this [a picture of]?

And the simple answer also implies the same unspoken information:

> That is [a picture of] a supermarket!

---

Why the two suggestions don't work well:

> Where is here?

It is really tough to understand how you want me to answer that. I would guess that you meant to say "Where is this?" but then that means you want the answer to be a more general location where the thing in the picture is. So even "Where is this?" doesn't work for a supermarket flashcard. It works better for landmarks, and you want the response to be the city or country the landmark is in.

> What is here?

This means you are asking for the people or objects that are in the location. So if you show a picture of a supermarket and ask "What is here?", then I will answer with a list of vocabulary words of things you find in a supermarket: "food, drinks, vegetables, worker, customer!".

Comment: Thanks! So simply we could ask "what is this?"

Comment: Exactly! And your students can say, "It is a ___." or "That is a ___." or just "a ___".