Why can we say "Where is THERE?" but not "Where is HERE?" to find out about a place?
On TV, a woman who thinks she is sent from outer space is talking about how she exchanged souls with something from the space. Here is a part from the conversation:
Presenter: Where did your soul go to?
Woman: There.
Presenter: Where is there? ITV - She believes she is sent from outer space (see: 4:08-4:13)
I remember asking a question whether I could ask "Where is here?" if I want to find out what the name of a place in photograph is, and I remember being answered "No, it would be wrong." And, instead, I was advised to use "Where is that? Where is this? What/Where is this place?/Where was this taken?"
But then the same thing happens here. And the TV presenter can very well form a question "Where is there?".
So, why can we ask "Where is THERE?" but not "Where is HERE?"

You can ask 'where is here?'. Who said you can't? You might put quotes around 'here' in writing, or use an emphasising tone of voice. Consider: we are in a long-distance bus at night. It stops in a small town (I don't know the name). The driver says 'We will have to stay here until the engine is repaired'. I raise my hand and ask 'Where is 'here'?. I want to use my phone to Google for a hotel, restaurant, or taxi company, and need the town name. Or my son calls on his mobile phone and says 'I am stuck here'. Again, I ask 'Where is 'here'?'.

@MichaelHarvey, thanks Michael. I am glad to learn I can ask "Where is here". Here is a link where it is not found to correct https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/178365/where-is-here-or-what-is-here

@MichaelHarvey, By the way, how do you answer a question like "Where is here?"? Can you answer "Here is London."?

Yes, but as I said, you emphasise 'here' when speaking.

And another one https://hinative.com/questions/129421

Yunus, you now have an answer which I believe is good. Not to toot my own horn or anything. ||I do not understand the downvote here. The problem is that many people do not understand how deictics work. Ergo, this is a good question. And I am sure MIchael Harvey will agree

I cannot understand why people want to close this question. Sour grapes? Deixis is really important.

Question: So, why can we ask "Where is THERE?" but not "Where is HERE?"
The whole point is the dialogue. That is what determines usage here, not grammar:
Presenter: Where did it go?
Woman: There.  [outer space, probably pointing]
Presenter: Where is there?
If the woman had said "here" (presumably pointing to something), the presenter would have used here, not there. "here" and "there" are deictics and follow slightly different rules which depend on the/a speech event/dialogue.
The words here and there in that dialogue refer to what the woman said which is then taken up again by the presenter. deictic words point to things in reality, referents.
Answer: So, we ask "Where is there?" or "Where is here?" depending on the situation in a dialogue. This is not really a grammatical issue.
*Here is London. or There is London. are perfectly acceptable in these situations.

Good explanation. Thanks. I have learnt something new. Regarding "where is here", I want to find out whether in English language, "here" only refers to the actual physical area someone is located. For instance I am not sure if "a place in a picture or on TV" does count as "here/there", doesn't it? Maybe that is why we can't ask "Where is here"?" about a city or a place that we see on a screen or in a photo or in a postcard?

@Yunus Yet somebody dv'ed it. Sour grapes, I assume.

Yes, here or there can refer to a place in a picture or other representative form if it is clear you referring to it in the course of the conversation or actually pointing to it.

If you want to know the location in a photograph showing a place, you can ask

What place is this?
Where was this picture taken?

"Where is here?" would be understood but it is not idiomatic.

Does "Where is there" work as in the case of the TV presenter asking his guest?

Where Is Here? is a collection containing 34 works of short fiction by Joyce Carol Oates originally published in paperback by Harper & Row in 1989... Just sayin'....

One swallow does not a summer make.

I don't understand why I can ask "Where is here?" to find out the name of a place if I am on a bus just woken up at night , but not to find the name of a place if I am looking at a photograph?

If someone  goes on about a place  like this:  "We went on vacation and I loved it there. The scenery was beautiful and the people were so friendly. The food was delicious." and either because you entered the conversation late (as at a party) or because the speaker is ditzy and never mentioned where they went, you could  ask "And where is 'there' ?"  You'd be quoting the speaker and would intone the word to let the speaker know that you're saying their own words back at them. It is a special case. That's the kind of case Michael Harvey was referring to in the comment about the bus trip.

It is decidely not idiomatic. It is a kind of "meta" speech act.

Similarly the speaker could have said "We went on vacation to a lovely place. The scenery ...."  and you could ask "And where is 'a lovely place'?"   That's not idiomatic either, but a similar special case. It is a tad snarky. To make it not so barbed you could ask "And what is the name of this lovely place you went to?"

"this" is still a shade unidiomatic ("that" would be more suitable), just enough to jog the speaker to let them know that you would like to know the name.

"Where is this", said the young lady pointing at the photograph from two inches away. This is all about deixis in speech (pragmatics). "And where is a lovely place?" is not idiomatic? Gees.

@Lambie  You're not reading carefully enough.
